# Looking for resources - Develop Power BI Custom Visuals with Angular

Tags: angular, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I prefer Angular over React and looking for some resources to get a simple custom visual working for Power BI. I'm not looking for details on the graphing side (e.g. Angular with D3), more just the relationship between Angular and Power BI Custom Visuals. If you know of any good links/sources or have even undertaken the challenge yourself, I would love to hear it.

I tried to take a stab at it myself, piecing together some poorly written and outdated blog posts, but couldn't get it to work and was left even more confused.

My understanding is I need to create the component as a custom element, bundle that into one file, then reference it within Power BI Visuals code. However, I couldn't find any exact information detailing that.

Edit: Worth noting, I'm trying with Angular v17.